# Ingress-Nginx Multi Cluster Service support

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, network-programming, nginx-ingress

We have an Nginx ingress controller that we use as a Load Balancer. We have a control application that we use to create accounts for clients and when our control application creates the deployment it also upserts a service and an ingress. The ingress is used to route the traffic to a specific client backend service.

[image]

So any requests to `https://our.website.com/client/1` are routed to the `client-1` service and any requests to  `https://our.website.com/client/2` are routed to the `client-2` service.

Now our product has matured and we have the need to be able to deploy customer backends to different clusters. We have looked at creating a Multi-cluster implementation like GCP suggests in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/multi-cluster-services). This is almost working for us but not exactly. The services can communicate with each other(we have other services also running) but NGINX is not able to see the Service Import. My question is does NGINX support mapping to Service Imports rather than just Services? If not is there a workaround to that or perhaps a different load balancer that would support that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I wasn't able to find a way to do that. We ended up implementing a mixed architecture where most of our apps such as the control ones and the React frontend are handled bt our current NGINX controller. We have also deployed a `gke-l7-gxlb-mc` Multi Cluster Gateway alongside out NGINX Load Balancer with a secondary URL `our-gw.website.com` This URL os used by our frontend only and is not visible to the clients.